# plot figure from a handle returned from a fucntion

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is it possible to have matlab return the handle of a number of figures from a function, and then the user can specify which figure to be displayed. For example:

```
function [fha, fh2, fh3] = my_funct(x,y)

    fh1 = figure(1);
    plot(x,y);

    fh2 = figure(2);
    plot(x,y*3);

    fh3 = figure(3);
    plot(x,y*7);
end
```

where x and y are any input vectors.

I realise that I can place an input variable which states which figure to return from the function, but I would like to be able for the user to select the figure that they wanted, from the outputs listed. Then, if necessary they can look at another figure. I would like to be able to do something like:

get(fh1, 'show_me_the_figure')

and this would show the first figure, from the handle that is returned from the function. Is this possible?

Comment: Does `figure(fh2)` do the job? Remember that in any case, if the figure is closed the handle will disapear!

Comment: I think Ander is spot on...

Comment: Yes, spot on. I have made the figures invisible in the function (visible = off) so your suggestion works great.

Comment: @EmmaTebbs happy to help! consider accepting one of the answers if your problem has been solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose which figure to show using `figure(handle)`, if handle was created with another `figure()` call before.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating 3 figures, how about you plot your specified figure according to the choice? Since `handle=figure(number);` will always generate a new window, or overwrite an existing window.
In a gui you can use a switch in your selection-callback, which uses the selected option in a switch (simple function example bellow).

```
function [fh] = my_funct(x,y,chosen)

switch chosen
   case 1
      fh = figure(1);
      plot(x,y);
   case 2
      fh = figure(1);
      plot(x,y*3);
   case 3
      fh = figure(1);
      plot(x,y*7);
   otherwise
      fh = figure(1);
      disp('No Valid Choice')
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I had initially, but then if I wanted to see the second figure I would need to re-run the function. This is not desireable in my case as the function takes some time to run.

Comment: Than how about you use assignin or save to save your results and use a seperate function to plot the chosen figure(s)?